# Как получить доступ к объекту из другого метода?

Tags: c#

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Data square = new Data();
        square._storona = 10;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       //как в этом методе получить доступ к объекту square НЕ используя статические поля.



    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private Data square;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    square = new Data();
    square._storona = 10;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // use square
}
```

или

```
private Data square = new Data() { _storona = 10 };

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // use square
}
```